# Passing Firestore document reference to flutter widget

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I am having trouble passing a Firestore document reference to a widget in Flutter. 
 The Idea is to have the class `Home` display a `ListView` of thumbnail images, which with the help of onTap route you to a `VideoView` that displays the video associated with the thumbnail image.

Now the Problem is that although I have all the classes and the layout set up, I am having trouble handing over the Firestore reference with the necessary metadata for the video to the `VideoView` class, like the url of the video in question or its title and comments.

All the thumbnail urls and the matching titles in the `Home` Widget are fetched from Firestore and added to the `ListView` as seen in the examples section [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore)

My plan is to have apart from the `title` and `thumbnailUrl` field in Firestore also a reference to the matching Video document which holds all the metadata necessary to display the video and its comments in the `VideoView` widget.

Is this possible with the cloud_firestore plugin in flutter right now and if so, how could I implement it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your data are loaded in your Home view you can simply pass the necessary data to the VideoView as constructor argument.

Comment: @aziza Because the comments are supposed to be loaded in a rate limited query I would like to query all the data in the VideoView widget itself. This is why I would like to pass a document reference to the VideoView and then query the metadata of the video from Firestore. Or is this not possible?

Comment: I can't get your question, do you want to pass the document id of firestore document snapshot to another page screen? You can get the document id from document snapshot `snapshot.documentID` and simply pass it to another page screen constructor

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification, I got it somewhat setup by passing the documentID to the VideoView widget. The only issue I have now is that I have no idea how to deal with the `DocumentReference`. I am trying to query the `channelName` attribute of the Document xyz. So what I tried is `Firestore.instance.document('videos/${DocumentId}/channelName').toString()` which didnt work. Do you maybe know a solutuion?

Answer (score 2):

**ListPage**

```
ListTile(
 onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailsPage(msg: snapshot.data.documents[index]))),
)
```

**DetailsPage**

When using statefull widget

```
class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {

  DocumentSnapshot msg;

  DecryptorPage({@required this.msg});

  @override
  _DecryptorPageState createState() => _DecryptorPageState();
}

class _DecryptorPageState extends State<DecryptorPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String msg = widget.msgs.data['msg'];
    return Container(
      child: Text('$msg)
    );
  }
}
```